# SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file' with EF Core code first

Tags: sqlite, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I am getting an

> SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'

with EF Core code first, no idea why. I worked fine the first time, the database file got created in `c:\users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PackageId\LocalState`.

Then I deleted the database file and the code first migration and `ModelSnapshot` classes and created a new migration (I am calling `DbContext.Database.Migrate()` on app start to automatically execute them). Now the database cannot be created again.

Answer (score 42):

i think the issue is that the EntityFramework Core can't create folders by itself while using SQLite provider. Don't know if the issue also appears when using other filebased database providers.

i had the same issue:
my datasource was something like:
**optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=c:\foo_db\bar_db.db");**

after i created the **"foo_db"** folder inside the c:\ drive, the problem was solved and EF Core created the .db file inside the folder.

Comment: This saved me hours! Thanks!
For whatever reason EF cannot create folders. Only the db file

Answer (score 6):

Solved it.

1. Activating "break on all exceptions" (in exceptions settings window) caused the weird 'unable to open database file' exception.
2. Removing the [Table("TableName")] attributes on my entity classes caused some strange table creation behavior in the migration class. I thought the attribute is only needed to create a table with another name than the class name.

Comment: I believe #2 is not related to it. It is not an issue (or error either). You deleted database. When you call Migrate (or even EnsureCreated), EF needs determine if the database already exists or not (so that it can create one if not existing). EF does that by connecting to database. If it is successful then database exists if it fails then it doesn't. Since you have break on all exceptions, it broke the code when you got exception while connecting to database. If you continue the execution then EF will catch the exception and create database for you.

Answer (score 6):

The Actual issue is after migration and database update *.db file doesn't go to bin folder automatically.
You Just need to select the *.db and change properties "Copy to Output Directory" = "Copy if newer".
This will resolve the issue.. please try and let us know.

Answer (score 3):

I also solved the problem by replacing "**InProcess**" in the project file (*.csproj) with "**OutOfProcess**". I hope it helps you too.

Comment: For those who want to understand how this works, basically `InProcess` means it will be running inside a IIS instance (alongside a bunch of configs) and `OutOfProcess` runs Kestrel. Here's the source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#hosting-models .

Comment: This comment assumes that the developer is writing a web application. For anyone writing desktop applications, console applications or windows service applications, this comment can be disregarded.

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this code inside your DbContext class :**

```
  protected override void OnConfiguring( DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var dbPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "YourDbName.db");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename = "+dbPath);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i Was in the Same Situation  my problem was fix by Moving down Down  like the pic :

[image]
 firts   `"AllowedHosts": "*",` and them

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "DbExample"
  }
```

thats happend to me with the Version NetCore 2.1 i hope this can help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

Still happening as of August 2019. Tried all of the above, but the fix for me after 2 good hours was this:

Add this class anywhere in the application:

```cs
internal class CurrentDirectoryHelpers
{
    internal const string AspNetCoreModuleDll = "aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll";
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(AspNetCoreModuleDll)]
    private static extern int http_get_application_properties(ref IISConfigurationData iiConfigData);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct IISConfigurationData
    {
        public IntPtr pNativeApplication;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public string pwzFullApplicationPath;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public string pwzVirtualApplicationPath;
        public bool fWindowsAuthEnabled;
        public bool fBasicAuthEnabled;
        public bool fAnonymousAuthEnable;
    }
    public static void SetCurrentDirectory()
    {
        try
        {
            // Check if physical path was provided by ANCM
            var sitePhysicalPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_IIS_PHYSICAL_PATH");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sitePhysicalPath))
            {
                // Skip if not running ANCM InProcess
                if (GetModuleHandle(AspNetCoreModuleDll) == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    return;
                }
                IISConfigurationData configurationData = default(IISConfigurationData);
                if (http_get_application_properties(ref configurationData) != 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                sitePhysicalPath = configurationData.pwzFullApplicationPath;
            }
            Environment.CurrentDirectory = sitePhysicalPath;
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}
```

Then, call it first thing in Program.cs, like this:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CurrentDirectoryHelpers.SetCurrentDirectory();
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

**My Setup**

- AspNet Core 2.2 Web API
- EF Core SQLite 2.2.6
- Connection String set to `"Filename=./mydatabase.db"`

**Credits**

I took it from this post:
https://elanderson.net/2019/02/asp-net-core-configuration-issue-with-in-process-hosting/

Answer (score 1):

In my case windows 10 Ransomware Protection was preventing LINQPad.DriverProxy.LINQPad.Drivers.EFCore.exe from accessing the file. Allowing it under ransomware protection -> block history prevented this error from being raised.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the same error was caused by using environment variable ("%APPDATA%) in path. Took me days to figure out that putting full path solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for me:

```
    static SqliteConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        string dbPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Database.sqlite";
        SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source = " + dbPath);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch { }
        return conn;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a web server like IIS, ensure that write access to both the SQLite database file and the directory containing that file is allowed (see this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/57596/why-do-i-get-sqlite-error-unable-to-open-database-file)) to the user used for running the app (which e.g. for IIS could be the [application pool identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced?view=aspnetcore-5.0#application-pool-identity)).